# Returning std::unordered_map<std::string, int> key as pybind11::bytes

Tags: c++, pybind11

Consider the following Pybind11 code:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

struct foo {
    foo() {
        data.emplace("\xde\xad\xbe\xaf", 1);
    }
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> data;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    pybind11::class_<foo>(m, "foo")
    .def(pybind11::init())
    .def_readonly("data", &foo::data);
}
```

When calling in python2 `example.foo().data`, it throws `UnicodeDecodeError` - because `data` keys do not contain valid UTF. Looking at pybind11/cast.h, we can see that `string_caster::cast()` always attempts to `decode_utfN()`, and that's what causes the above exception.

How to convince Pybind11 to treat the keys as `bytes`?

Answer (score 1):

How about copying values to a `dict` with `bytes` as keys? Would that work?

```
struct foo {
    foo() {
        data.emplace("\xde\xad\xbe\xaf", 1);
    }
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> data;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    pybind11::class_<foo>(m, "foo")
            .def(pybind11::init())
            .def_property_readonly("data", [](const foo& f)
                                   {
                                       pybind11::dict d;
                                       for(const auto& v : f.data )
                                       {
                                           d[pybind11::bytes(v.first)] = v.second;
                                       }
                                       return d;
                                   });
}
```

```
>>> import example
>>> example.foo().data
{b'\xde\xad\xbe\xaf': 1}
>>>
```

Comment: Well, that would create a new object. The question is whether it's possible to wrap the original one.

Comment: I am not pybind11 expert, but I checked in the headers, that in your case, if you cast to `std::string` a `PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8` `CPython` function is going to be called. That creates a new object too. I have never created a proxy but I have seen them in `pybind11/numpy.h` header files. For instance `array_caster` from `pybind11/stl.h` creates new list and appends new objects to it. So I think "casting" creates new objects. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.